# Setter and getter methods php

Tags: php, arrays, setter, getter

I have made a class named PriviewMode

```
class PriviewModel {

    private $TOPIC_ID = array();  
    private $SECTION_ID = array(); 
    private $ADDITION_TEXT_SEQ = array(); 
    private $TOPIC_HYPERLINK = array(); 
    private $TOPIC_NAME = array(); 
    private $TOPIC_TEXT = array(); 
    private $CATEGORY_ID = array(); 
    private $CONTRIBUTED_BY = array(); 
    private $APPROVED_FOR_LIVE = array(); 
    private $LAST_UPDATED = array(); 

    function getTOPIC_ID() {
    return $this->TOPIC_ID;
    }

   function getSECTION_ID() {
    return $this->SECTION_ID;
    }

   function getADDITION_TEXT_SEQ() {
   return $this->ADDITION_TEXT_SEQ;
   }

  function getTOPIC_HYPERLINK() {
  return $this->TOPIC_HYPERLINK;
  }

 function getTOPIC_NAME() {
  return $this->TOPIC_NAME;
 }

 function getTOPIC_TEXT() {
  return $this->TOPIC_TEXT;
 }

 function getCATEGORY_ID() {
  return $this->CATEGORY_ID;
 }

 function getCONTRIBUTED_BY() {
  return $this->CONTRIBUTED_BY;
 }

 function getAPPROVED_FOR_LIVE() {
  return $this->APPROVED_FOR_LIVE;
 }

 function getLAST_UPDATED() {
  return $this->LAST_UPDATED;
 }

 function setTOPIC_ID($TOPIC_ID) {
  $this->TOPIC_ID = $TOPIC_ID;
 }

 function setSECTION_ID($SECTION_ID) {
  $this->SECTION_ID = $SECTION_ID;
  }

  function setADDITION_TEXT_SEQ($ADDITION_TEXT_SEQ) {
  $this->ADDITION_TEXT_SEQ = $ADDITION_TEXT_SEQ;
   }

  function setTOPIC_HYPERLINK($TOPIC_HYPERLINK) {
  $this->TOPIC_HYPERLINK = $TOPIC_HYPERLINK;
  }

  function setTOPIC_NAME($TOPIC_NAME) {
  $this->TOPIC_NAME = $TOPIC_NAME;
  }

  function setTOPIC_TEXT($TOPIC_TEXT) {
  $this->TOPIC_TEXT = $TOPIC_TEXT;
  }

  function setCATEGORY_ID($CATEGORY_ID) {
  $this->CATEGORY_ID = $CATEGORY_ID;
  }

  function setCONTRIBUTED_BY($CONTRIBUTED_BY) {
  $this->CONTRIBUTED_BY = $CONTRIBUTED_BY;
  }

  function setAPPROVED_FOR_LIVE($APPROVED_FOR_LIVE) {
  $this->APPROVED_FOR_LIVE = $APPROVED_FOR_LIVE;
  }

  function setLAST_UPDATED($LAST_UPDATED) {
  $this->LAST_UPDATED = $LAST_UPDATED;
  }
```

and create some getter and setter method for it. The variables are array. Now the problem is how set the resultset of a mysql_fetch_object in this class varibles. like

```
foreach($results as $result){

 $privewmodel->setTOPIC_ID($result->topic_id);
       .....
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: how to set the array variable with setters, ' $privewmodel->setTOPIC_ID($result->topic_id);'  is a invalid methos i suppose

Comment: It is completely unclear what you ask. You mention mysql between the lines. Does that mean you want to use a database connection? If so, where is your code for that?

Comment: Ok, the problem is not about the database connection, If I state the problem precisely, then how to set array variables in a class with the setter like this, and how to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this is what you need:

```
$previousValue = $privewmodel->getTOPIC_ID();
$newValue = array_merge($previousValue, $result->topic_id);
$privewmodel->setTOPIC_ID($newValue);
```

Basically get your current array, and append the new value to it with `array_merge()`.